# Big O notation preserved under convex functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose that the random variable $X_T$ is $O_p(1)$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$, i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists M_\epsilon>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_T>M_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ $\forall T$.

Does this imply that the random variable $\max\{0,X_T \}$ is $O_p(1)$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: what does it mean for a rv to be $O(\cdot)$?

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a real number $x$, $\max\{0,x\}\leqslant |x|$, hence 
$$\{\max\{0,X_T\}>M\}\subset |X_T|>M\}$$
and the conclusion follows.